# How to send distance variable from app.py to english.html with Flask

Tags: python, html, opencv, flask

I measure distance with OpenCV. Then I draw it on the screen with Flask. If the distance is less than 50, I want the Icardi video to be shown, otherwise the Messi video to be shown.
But I cannot send the distance variable to the html file.

distance = int(math.sqrt(int(x2 - x1) ** 2 + int(y2 - y1) ** 2))

I want to send this variable to the html page.
I want to use if else in the HTML page.

How do you think I can do this?

App.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template , Response

import mediapipe as mp
import cv2
import math
app = Flask(__name__)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
pose = mpPose.Pose()

def generate_frames():
    import mediapipe as mp
    import cv2
    mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
    pose = mpPose.Pose()
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame2 = frame
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = pose.process(imgRGB)
        cv2.flip(frame,0)
        if results.pose_landmarks:

            for id, lm in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark):
                h, w, c = frame2.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                if id == 7:
                    x1, y1 = cx, cy
                    cv2.circle(frame, (cx, cy), 6, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                if id == 21:
                    x2, y2 = cx, cy
                    cv2.circle(frame, (cx, cy), 6, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)

            distance = int(math.sqrt(int(x2 - x1) ** 2 + int(y2 - y1) ** 2))
            cv2.putText(frame, "mesafe:" + str(distance), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 255), 2)
            if (x2 <= 640) & (x1 <= 640) & (y2 <= 480) & (y1 <= 480):
                cv2.line(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 255), 2)
        if not ret:
            break
        else:
            ret,buffer=cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame)
            frame=buffer.tobytes()

        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video')
def video():
    return Response(generate_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


@app.route('/english')
def english():
    return render_template('english.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

English.HTML

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="column">
          <img src="{{ url_for('video') }}" width="450" height="320"/>
        </div>

      **{% if distance<50 %}**
            <div class="column">

          **???????? What code should I write here?**

        </div>
        {% endif %}


  </div>
```

Comment: Why are you using duplicated import mediapipe as mp and  import cv2?

Comment: There is no particular reason. I didn't pay attention.